# Error in deployment step 'Activate Features'

Tags: visual-studio, error, deployment

Every time I try to deploy my project (containing only one Event Receiver), I get the following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Operation is
>   not valid due to the current state of the object.

I simply restart Visual Studio and Redeploy and it works. But I have to do this everytime I want to deploy. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: http://suehernandez.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object/

Comment: if you give us more details about what you doing in event receiver, may be somebody help you...this guy is talking about list event receiver...http://apartha77.blogspot.com/2012/03/error-occurred-in-deployment-step_29.html

Comment: It could be something in my elements file. Thanks for this link I'll try eliminating some tags

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy a web part for a farm and you try to activate it from the feature it will not work because you need to activate it from a site, you cannot do it a deployment time and it will give you an error.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efa77726-3092-49f6-a79f-17bc1d1b196c/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-add-solution-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: I have dozens of web parts that target a farm and I Activate at deployment time. And why would it work upon restarting VS?

Comment: Do you retract and deploy everytime ??

Comment: Same result if I try retracting first

Comment: nowhere i could find why issue occurs intermittent . but similar issue is discussed here .http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/deploying-eventreceiver-project-with-target-of-webapplication-from-vs-fails-when/27409